# Get user_id based data in google analytics 4

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, userid

Currently I'm logging events using firebase analytics, but I want to have one user specific data like whatever user has done, I want all info using just userid.

Using **firebase_analytics** : in flutter.
I have tried turning on user_id enabled in google analytics/admin/reporting identify/

But I have not succeeded to get a view with specific user based view.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution these articles helped me first make sure to setUserId() using goole analytics and attach your firebase project from default google analytics to new google analytics project. Go to explorer -> open timeline -> user explorer.
Now u can see user specific data (This will reflects after some time user generates data)

**Resources** 
[article 1](https://phppot.com/php/track-individual-logged-in-users-using-google-analytics/) 
[article 2](https://www.ruleranalytics.com/blog/analytics/google-analytics-user-tracking/)